# Insulating the space under our kitchen

Tags: insulation

We bought a house about 6 months ago that has a kitchen addition (house is about 110 years old-not sure about addition). Over the winter we have learned that the space underneath must not be insulated very well, as the floors are freezing. There is an access to this space, but it isn't really a "crawl space"  as not even a small person could fit under there. I think the best thing to do is to insulate when we redo the floors. However, we don't know the best way to insulate it. I haven't gotten a good look underneath yet, but I am assuming it is a dirt floor, and that there is VERY little space between the ground and the floor above. Our kitchen drain pipes run under there as well, which has caused some problems with freezing this winter-another reason it needs insulation.

Comment: Are the vents through the foundation open or closed?  Normally, they should be closed in winter to prevent freezing air from moving under the house.